# How can I get a file I selected in a file select control in file1.html, trough javascript, into file2.php to be processed

Tags: php, javascript, html

The structure looks like this:

```
<form>
...
some stuff
...
file select
...
some stuff
...
</form>
```

I need to send the input data from "file select" while not sending "some stuff" and as far as i've tried I couldn't get a form inside another form so that's not an option.

The way it works is like this: the file select control isn't displayed at first, clicking a button makes it show the control and some other stuff. I need a button to submit that file to be checked for different things (naming, size, etc) and uploaded to the server, without changing or reloading the rest of the window.

I could change the layout a bit and get the file select stuff out of the form but the boss doesn't want to change the design of the window and removing the outer-most form will be a lot of work as it's a very complicated part of the web site.

So, as the question says: Can I do it? Can I get the file trough javascript and send it to another php file for processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most browser compatible way to achieve this is to use a hidden `iframe` that you submit the form into. For example:

```
<iframe name="my_iframe" id="my_iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>

<form action="/next_step.php" method="post" target="my_iframe" entype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" />
    <input type="button" id="upload_btn" value="Upload file" />

    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

    <input type="submit" value="Next step" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById('upload_btn');
    btn.onclick = function(){
        var form_elem = document.forms[0];
        // direct file uploads through the hidden iframe
        form_elem.action = '/test_file.php';
        form_elem.target = 'my_iframe';

        // submit the form
        form_elem.submit();

        // now reset for next step in the form
        form_elem.action = '/next_step.php';
        form_elem.target = null;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Makes sense, I'm already submitting to an iFrame so i don't need that but I'm gonna try your solution. Thanks and I'll let you know how it works out.

Comment: I'm having a problem with your solution. It works great for setting the new action and the file gets sent but I can't get it to run a javascript in the target. I echo a javascript tag with something in it (in this case an alert to see wether it works) from the action script, and it shows up in the target (checked with both firebug and expanded the "invisible" iframe to see wether it recieves any data) but the javascript just won't fire.

Comment: Nevermind, dumbass co-worker set the content-type as text/xml. sigh.